# preposition "for" vs "of"

Tags: prepositions

Would a teacher, on the point of proposing a correction to his students, say: "Let's make / here is the correction FOR the test or the correction OF the test? Or "Here is a summary FOR the story or OF the story?
Thanks for helping me making a choice!

Answer (score 6):

Either preposition could be used and would have a slightly different connotation.

In the example "Here is the correction OF the test", using OF implies that the correction and the test are the same entity and the correction is a component of the test.

In the example "Here is the correction FOR the test", using FOR implies that the correction is a separate entity designed specifically for usage on the test.

Answer (score 1):

Prepositions are flexible and there's not necessarily only one that will do the job.

That said, I'd be inclined to use *to*, I think:

> Let's make a correction **to** the test.

Of course, you can skirt the problem altogether by rephrasing:

> Let's correct the test.

As for summary, that should be *of*:

> Here is a summary *of* the story.

Comment: As a footnote, you might want to check out [ell.se]. You can read about the difference between ELU and ELL at [this meta question](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/3722). I think this might be a better fit over there.